# Oracle installation on AWS

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, oracle11g

I just installed http://aws.amazon.com/amis/oracle-database-11g-release-2-11-2-0-1-standard-edition-64-bit/ on AWS.
I'm able to login to my EC2.

a) How should I connect my Oracle using Oracle SQL developer remotely?
b) On Oracle Linux, how do I login to Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods - the easy way and the more secure way.

1. Easy way: open port 1521 in the Security Group used by your EC2 instance*. In SQL Developer, connect to the public DNS for your EC2 instance.
2. More secure way: open SSH (port 22) in the Security Group used by your EC2 instance*. In SQL Developer (version 4.0.3 required) use SSH tunnelling - refer to http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/09/30-sql-developer-tips-in-30-days-day-17-using-ssh-tunnels/. You will need your ppk that you generated when you created the instance. I use this method now exclusively.

* Preferably, limit it to your local IP address (i.e. don't open these ports to 0.0.0.0).

If you need to run commands in SQL*Plus in Linux, just do something like (e.g. using PuTTY):

```
su - oracle
sqlplus /nolog
```